# squid proxy doesn't let me download

Tags: proxy, squid

my university use squid as it's proxy server for configuring the access to the web; so to access the internet, I should provide my applications with host ip, port, my username and my password(which causes a lot of pain because some applications don't support such proxy settings); anyway;

the problem is that they configured the proxy server in such a way that if you try to access or download an url which ended with "*part1.rar" or "*.001", the proxy denies access;

anyway to download such files?

Comment: Find a file provider that uses https.

Comment: quick and dirty: use a proxy site..  `zend2.com` for example!

Comment: Don't use the proxy. If that doesn't work, then you don't have Internet access, you have access to a web proxy, and should consider getting actual Internet access.